# Using unique identifiers for selection in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Please I need your help on writing a formula in excel. It's meant to be basic but for just one thing, it's not basic anymore. I'm going to be describing the problem as good as I can.

So I have a cell say E9 and the left is D9 obviously. Now E9 is empty, but D9 is not and has a name in it. There's another cell say L9 which has to its right, M9. Both are filled up but L9 has the same name as D9 (remember E9 is empty) and M9 has a numerical value. Now E9 should derive its value from M9 or the cell which has the same name as D9 which in this case happened to be L9

so its not E9 = M9 
its more like E9 = M9 because , L9 = D9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
=VLOOKUP(D9,$L$9:$M$17,2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=INDEX($M$9:$M$17,MATCH(D9,$L$9:$L$17,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you. Thanks @ Mrig

Comment: Whoa. Thanks a lot @ Mrig. I don't know how you did it but it sure did work. Thanks again. I really appreciate this

Comment: @IfeoluwaOlatunde - For details on `VLOOKUP` see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Answer (score 0):

So here's something attached to this. 
I found a formula to print some parts of a cell.

=RIGHT(M9, LEN(M9)- 1) - That's a sample of what the formula looks like.

So I get a result from what you(Mrig) helped me with but the result has an alphabet attached to it which is correct.

the alphabet, however, is always the first character in the string. So I don't know if you can help eradicate the alphabet by maybe nesting the function into the Vlookup function

thanks.

Example: From your picture, You can assume L9 has a value of $9 so that under Number column, there's a value error. I hope you understand this?